# binary FTP transfer of .txt file -- Unix to Windows

Tags: shell, ftp, binary, file-transfer

I am trying to ftp a text file from a Unix machine to a Windows machine. In the process, the data is getting mangled. I want to try transfering the file in binary instead of ASCII - hopefully that will make the data pass thru without getting corrupted.

How can I modify the following script to make the .txt file transfer as a binary file, instead of ASCII? I am not familiar with the syntax.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set uname=john
    set passw=password
    set hostname=johncomputer
    set filespec=SampleSPEC
echo %uname%>                     name.ftp
echo %passw%>>                    name.ftp
echo cd CRMD>>                    name.ftp
echo get %filespec%>>             name.ftp
echo bye>>                        name.ftp
ftp -s:name.ftp %hostname%
if errorlevel 1 pause
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `echo TYPE I >> name.ftp` before the line that adds the `get` command.

Comment: thanks - can you link me to some documentation that explains what this does?